# Does the target for Double-Take replication require an Oracle license?

Tags: oracle, replication, license

Where would Vision Solution's [Double-Take](http://www.visionsolutions.com/Products/DT-Avail.aspx) product fall with regard to Oracle Licensing?  It is both a backup and a replication of the database.  Oracle's [Software Investment Guide](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/sig-070616.pdf) has a section on Backup, Standby, Failover, and Remote Mirroring.  My concern is that this product would fall under remote mirroring and the server would need to be licensed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.  You should contact the vendor and get an answer in writing.

Comment: I did contact Oracle, see my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, Leigh - I did notice that; we've been having discussions about what licensing questions are on-topic for the DBA.SE site.  This question will likely be closed since we don't want to proffer advice to future readers that *many or may not* apply to them.   See this meta-question for details: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/487/are-licensing-questions-within-our-scope?cb=1

Comment: @MaxVernon Understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a conference call with our Oracle Technology Sales Manager and an Oracle Solution Consultant.  We discussed the Double-Take setup and they were able to confirm that based on the way we have our DR site setup and our primary site licensed, we do NOT need to license the DR site.  This is of course assuming we do not deviate from the setup we discussed with them.  This somewhat surprised me and should in no way be looked at as an indicator Oracle's stance on Double-Take for any other installation than ours.

Answer (score 3):

From the document, the important paragraph is:

> To setup a remote mirroring
>   environment, the Oracle data files,
>   **executables, binaries** and DLLs are
>   replicated to the mirrored storage
>   unit. Solutions like Veritas Volume
>   Replicator, EMC SRDF, Legato
>   Replistor, and EMS StoreEdge are used
>   to mirror the data stored on the disk
>   arrays.

Emphasis mine. If you are just mirroring the DBFs then that's one thing, but if you can ever "activate" that standby, then it must be licensed.

> If the Oracle Database is accessing
>   the data from the primary disk array
>   and it is not accessing the mirrored
>   disk array, **but it is installed on the
>   mirrored network storage unit**, then
>   both database must be fully licensed
>   and the same metric must be used

I don't think they will let you get away with having a copy of the Oracle CDs at the remote site with the instructions "only install in event of failure" either :-)

Comment: I thought there was some leeway if the aforementioned standby could prove to not be active for less than a certain amount of the year...(equating to maybe less than a day). I can't remember the doc or article.

Comment: You can run on alternate kit for up to 10 days/year for planned maintenance, but if we're talking DR then there's no way you can assume that if something takes out your primary DC that you can be back in that time.

Comment: I really thought Oracle would tell us that it required a license and I would mark your answer as accepted.  They did not (see my answer).  Thank you for your input it verified that I was reading the document they same way someone else would even if Oracle came to a different conclusion. +1